# How do you incorporate banner ads into a mobile optimized site (using mobile CSS overwrite)?

Tags: css

I am currently working on a mobile optimized site using a mobile CSS stylesheet (which loads that adapts the existing page structure and serves that style to the phone browser). Client would like to integrate ad banners or ad space. How does it work from the front end and the backend? Any advice/recommendations are well recommended?

Thank you.

Comment: the front end displays the users the content, the back end ( i presume you mean the server code? ) makes no difference to the end user. Assume (if you are using AdSense) that these will be text only ads. I will just point out that if I ever visited a mobile site full of banner ads I would never again be visiting that site.

Answer (score 0):

From the media query driven CSS side there's nothing you can do (unless you want to load all the possible ad sizes and then display: none the ones that don't fit the layout at a given size, but that's probably not a good idea for (a) performance reasons and (b) it will annoy the advertisers).

Talk to your client's ad agency - as more and more sites switch to adaptive layouts it's in their interests to supply sites with code that detects screen size and loads appropriately sized ads. Ideally we'd be able to do something like this:

```
<div id="ad_slot_1"></div>
....
<div id="ad_slot_2"></div>
....
<div id="ad_slot_3"></div>
....
<script src="http://www.example.com/adverts.js"></script>
```

where the script will detect the screen size and load different ads. Maybe an MPU in slot 2 and a leaderboard in slot 3 on desktop but mini-banners in slots 1 and 2 on mobile.

If the ad agency can't deliver (and considering the low quality javascript they've been dishing out for years this wouldn't be surprising) and your client won't shop around for a better agency then you may have to use something like Wurfl on the server to detect the user's device and make a best guess as to whether it's mobile or not and then write different ad fetching scripts into the page depending. This won't work perfectly and won't be adaptive - rotate your phone or tablet or resize your desktop window and the layout will change but the ads won't.

Finally, an idea that I plan to prototype in the new year is basically a DIY version of what I'd like to see ad networks supply. Create an iframe dynamically from JavaScript which can detect the screen size and can pass this back to the server which loads different ad fetching code in the iframe. As well as being adaptive this can also make the ad loading asynchronously unlike most code that the ad networks provide. For some ad networks it may be possible to skip the iframe and load different ad fetching code directly via JavaScript. I'd be interested to hear from anyone who has already tried this.